# Increasing size of Custom UITableViewCell that contains 2 UILabel

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I'm working on a `UITableView`. In my app I'm to show some data in 2 sections and I have a `custom cell`, actually in `customCell` I have 2 `UILabel` `label1 & label2`.
First `section` is ok because it has simple data to show but when I show 2nd section where I have 4 rows to show, out of 3 rows has much bigger `string` to show. So to show that label I am increasing height of Cell and UILabel view.

to increase height of Cell I implemented method `heightForRowAtIndexPath` as below

```
- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (1 == indexPath.section && 0 != indexPath.row)
    {
        return _profileTableView.rowHeight + 50.0;        
    }
    else
    {
        return _profileTableView.rowHeight;
    }

}
```

Problem in `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method is that, only 3rd and 4rth row's size getting increased and when I'm trying to set new frame to  label1 and label2, no change appears.Labels getting appears very down in the cell.

this is how I implemented `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    ISClientProfileCell *cell = nil;

    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = (CustomCell *)[nib objectAtIndex:0];
    cell.label1.font = [UIFont fontWithName:defaultFont size:18];
    cell.label2.font = [UIFont fontWithName:defaultBoldFont size:18];

    if(0 == indexPath.section)
    {
        // first section is fine
    }
    else
    {
        switch (indexPath.row)
        {
            case 0:
            {
                cell.label1.text  = @"Data 1:";
                [cell.label1 sizeToFit];
                CGRect frame = cell.label1.frame;
                frame.origin.y = 11;
                cell.label1.frame = frame;

                frame = cell.label2.frame;
                frame.origin.x = cell.label1.frame.size.width + cell.label1.frame.origin.x+5;
                frame.origin.y = 11;
                cell.label2.frame = frame;
                cell.label2.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:key];
                [cell.label2 sizeToFit];
                break;
            }

            case 1:
            {              
                cell.label2.numberOfLines = 5;
                cell.label2.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByClipping;
                cell.label1.text = @"Data 2:";
                [cell.label1 sizeToFit];
                CGRect frame = cell.label1.frame;
                frame.origin.y = 11;
                cell.label1.frame = frame;

                frame = cell.label2.frame;
                frame.origin.x = cell.label1.frame.size.width + cell.label1.frame.origin.x+5;
                frame.origin.y = 11;
                cell.label2.frame = frame;
                cell.label2.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:aKey];
                [cell.label2 sizeToFit];

                break;
            }

            case 2:
            {  
                cell.label2.numberOfLines = 5;
                cell.label2.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByClipping;              
                cell.label1.text = @"Data 2:";
                [cell.label1 sizeToFit];
                CGRect frame = cell.label1.frame;
                frame.origin.y = 11;
                cell.label1.frame = frame;

                frame = cell.label2.frame;
                frame.origin.x = cell.label1.frame.size.width + cell.label1.frame.origin.x+5;
                frame.origin.y = 11;
                cell.label2.frame = frame;
                cell.label2.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:bKey];
                [cell.label2 sizeToFit];
                break;
            }

            case 3:
            {
                cell.label2.numberOfLines = 5;
                cell.label2.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByClipping;
                cell.label1.text = @"Data 2:";
                [cell.label1 sizeToFit];
                CGRect frame = cell.label1.frame;
                frame.origin.y = 11;
                cell.label1.frame = frame;

                frame = cell.label2.frame;
                frame.origin.x = cell.label1.frame.size.width + cell.label1.frame.origin.x+5;
                frame.origin.y = 11;
                cell.label2.frame = frame;
                cell.label2.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:cKey];
                [cell.label2 sizeToFit];
                break;
            }                

        }
    }

    return cell;
}
```

I searched enough but no answer worked for me. 
Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Might be you are getting wrong with table height. Ok tell me _profileTableView.rowHeight

Comment: Guys I had a very stupid issue in this, I was displaying a custom separator and problem was in adjusting that separator.
well thank you all for your efforts and answers.

Answer (score 1):

try this code:-

```
  - (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        if (indexPath.section !=0 && indexPath.row !=0)
        {
            return 44.0 + 50.0;        
        }
        else
        {
            return _profileTableView.rowHeight;
        }

     return 44.0;
    }
```

i hope it will help you to solve your problem.

Comment: hi @Suryakant Sharma. Is this working for you? so i can help you further

Answer (score 0):

Try to use different CellIdentifier for your cells. This way the tableview does not misplace the content of your cells on the reusablecell call.